# iOS: Is it possible to access stored data (say images) from the Safari browser

Tags: ios

My IT dept. has a web app built with java and they want to be able to access the stored images on an iPad. Is that possible?

Comment: It's not clear to me, from your question, where these images are stored.

Comment: Sorry, from the iOS Photo Library, say a user takes a photo using his iPad, would that photo then be accessible from the Safari browser through a Java app?

Comment: My understanding is no, you need to either develop natively or use something like PhoneGap to wrap in a web view so you can get hooks into device centric stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS Safari browser does not run Java. But, as of iOS 6, it does support uploading saved images with a standard HTML file upload form.

Comment: Thanks, was just looking to get confirmation on this.